# I have a hard time understanding why $\ln e=1$

Tags: logarithms

I have a hard time understanding why $\ln e=1$

Can someone explain to me why the natural logarithm of e is exactly equal to the first nonzero but positive integer?

Comment: Because $e^1 = e$? You always have $\log_a a = 1$, since $a^1 = a$.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function) article might prove itself useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is the definition of $\ln$ (logarithm in base e):

if you take $\log_2$ (logarithm in base 2) then $\log_2(2)=1$ and $\log_2(e) = 1/\ln(2)$

Comment: $\log_2$ or $\operatorname{lb}$ please... I have never seen people writing $\ln_2$...

Comment: I've edited your answer for the sake of posterity: please be advised by peterwhy's comment regarding using appropriate notation. The "gist" of your answer is spot on; but it's in everyone's best interest to use notation that is going to clarify and not mystify.

Comment: the best answer on mathematics.stackexchange so far

Comment: you're absolutely a genius

Comment: don't make fun of me, rope ! it is my first answer ever (-;

Comment: i'm serious !!!

Answer (score 6):

It depends on how you *define* the natural logarithm; but, let's do it this way:

By definition, $\ln(x)$ is the unique number $y$ such that $e^y=x$.  In other words, the natural logarithm $g(x)=\ln(x)$ is the *inverse function* for the exponential function $f(x)=e^x$.

So, $\ln(e)=1$ because $e^1=e$.

Comment: Why $e^1=e$ ? ?

Comment: Because $x^1=x$ for any $x$!  Remember that for any positive integer $n$, you can think of $x^n$ as the result of multiplying $n$ copies of $x$; if $n=1$, then you have only one copy.

Answer (score 0):

$In()$ means the logarithm with base $e$ if I say $\log_{e}(e)$ I am asking how many times I should multiply $e$ to 1 to get $e$. Or in other words we are trying to figure out the value of x in :-

$$e^x=e$$

We know anything raised to the first power or 1 is itself. You would probably know it.

So I can say:-

$$e^x=e
\\e^1=e
\\\therefore x=1 $$

And this means:-

$$In(e)=1$$

You can think about it in exponential form if it is not clear in logarithm as I showed you.

You can say $x^1=x$ as it says multiply x to 1 1 times and that is $1×x=x$ I know that people would say that we do not multiply by 1 in exponential but the number itself well what I think is adding and additional 1 causes no change and it is useful for negative exponents so according to me $x^2=1×x×x$

Answer (score -2):

A logarithm (being a function) along with a base $b$, when given an input $x$, could be interpreted as "What is $y$ such that $x=b^y$".
So if $b=e$, when evaluating $\log_e(e)=\ln(e)$, we actually ask "What is $y$ such that $e=e^y$". Therefore $\ln(e)=y=1$ must hold..

Comment: You can try adding more details